# Can I use impdp FULL=Y for an Oracle database charset conversion?

Tags: oracle, character-set, impdp

I need create a copy of an Oracle 12.2 instance (Oracle Restart) running on an Linux VM. The new instance needs a charset conversion from WE8ISO8859P1 to UTF8

I started by creating a clone of the VM that is now up and running.

I was thinking about following these steps:

1. expdp FULL=YES from the cloned machine to a safe storage location
2. destroy the database from the clone using DBCA
3. create a new database on the clone using DBCA setting UTF-8 as charset
4. impdp FULL=YES from the previous exported datapump

I have some doubts about the impdp FULL=YES... will this work or will it overwite some configuration on SYS or other Oracle maintained schemas with some values that still refers to WE8ISO8859P1 charset?

Will this work or should I exclude all the Oracle maintained schemas from the impdp?

Comment: Watch out, your varchar2 columns may not be wide enough to hold a string converted from we8iso8859p1 to UTF-8.

Comment: Sure, the character length semantic is a topic I do know very well ad I already modified on the source database on both objects definition and PL/SQL code variable declaration

Comment: OK, couldn't tell from your profile what your experience was.  Hope you are in good health, better than your avatar.

Comment: Keep in mind that conversion from Latin-1 (1-byte charset) to UTF-8 (multi-byte charset) has effects on "varchar length". For example, a varchar2 column at max size full with umlauts would no longer fit into your UTF8 column of the same size. See [my article here](https://www.izzysoft.de/oracle/articles/migration) on details; note that with 12c you can take advantage of "extended varchar2" with 32k size, so you won't need the CLOB work-around described (i couldn't do that on 9i more than 10 years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On export the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-BA07401C-6261-4B07-AD2C-06CD0A6E0BE9) states:

```
A full export does not, by default, export system schemas that contain Oracle-managed data 
and metadata. Examples of system schemas that are not exported by default include 
SYS, ORDSYS, and MDSYS.
```

If you want to be absolutely sure I would switch to a schema-mode import instead. You can still use the full export. That way you specify what schemas you want to import.

Regards,
Daniel